# Using require in node without just code and not a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, require

I have code in a database that has different node modules in it.  Like this:

```
exports.hello = hello
```

Normally, I would just use `hello = require './hello.js'`.  However, becuase the code is stored in the db, I can't include a path to the file.  When I try and do

`eval unescape hello_from_db_code` doesn't work.

Is there a way to get the `require` functionality without having a path to the file?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the code is stored in the db'? Can you please edit the question to make it more understandable?

Comment: by code is stored in the db, means that I have `exports.hello = hello` stored as a field in a row in a database instead of in a file

Comment: Just curious, what do you get when you print hello_from_db_code out to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think you can use require for this. see [here](http://adibaron.com/blog/2012/12/node-exports-require/)...

however, you can read the code from the db, eval it, and then export it.

anyway, try avoiding hacks that will trash your modules cache.

Answer (score 1):

If 'doesn't work' is 'module is not exported and there are undefined globals' then you can try to eval with missing references in the context:

```
vm = require 'vm'
requireFromString = (str, filename) ->
  sandbox =
    module:
      exports: {}
    require: require
    __filename: filename
  vm.runInNewContext(src, sandbox, filename)
  sandbox.module.exports
```

You may want to add extra references to sandbox, look at `Module.prototype._compile` function in [module.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js). Also you can access it directly as `hello = module._compile(hello_from_db_code)`